# Get model name dynamically in cakephp 2.x

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp-2.3

Is there any function to get the all table or model names in cakePhp.
I want to update my table's field and for that I need to select all table dynamically so that in future when I'll add new table I do not have to make changes in function.
The new table automatically update the fields.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the question - from what i gather you want to write abstract actions to account for multiple models? If this is the case you can add abstract actions into the AppController and use `$this->modelClass`. This will return the model name from were you are calling the abstract action from. For example if you calling the abstract action from 'UsersController' which by default uses the Model 'User' then the modelClass will return 'User'.

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public function abstractAdd() {
        // Get the model in use
        $this->{$this->modelClass}->create();
        // Use the save method in that model
        if ($this->{$this->modelClass}->save($data)) {
            // do something
        }         
    }

}

class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function add() {
        $this->abstractAdd();
    }

}
```

Hope this helps